# Today Widget debugging: Crashes not showing up in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, testflight, today-extension

I have several beta users who are testing (via TestFlight Internal Testing) an app I've built which features a Today widget. Many of them are reporting frequent crashes (The widget appears, then when it attempts to update, the "Unable To Load" message appears in its place). I've replicated it on my own phone as well.

However, TestFlight is reporting zero crashes, even after this has been going on for several days. Does this have to do with the fact that it's the extension, rather than the main app, that's crashing? If so, how can I get at the extension's crash logs?

Comment: Does TestFlight appear to miss all crashes or only the ones originating from the Today extension?

Comment: @spassas haven't encountered any crashes in the main app, so no idea... it's an extremely simple one-screen app, the widget is the focus.

Comment: There is a bunch of complaints and quite a few rdars about TestFlight missing crashes at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5396 Ι'm fairly certain that I have received TF crash reports from notification centre extensions in the past (although I cannot verify it right now)